# Using Python Regex to find a phrase between 2 tags

Tags: python, regex

I've got a string that I want to use regex to find the characters encapsulated between two known patterns, "Cp_6%3A" then some characters then "&" and potentially more characters, or no & and just the end of string.

My code looks like this:

```
def extract_id_from_ref(ref):
  id = re.search("Cp\_6\%3A(.*?)(\& | $)", ref)
  print(id)
```

But this isn't producing anything, Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reference the match group ...

Comment: i.e. do `id.group(0)` or whatever item you want. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `(\& | $)` matches either the `&` char and a space after it, or a space and end of string (the spaces are meaningful here!).

Use a negated character class `[^&]*` (zero or more chars other than `&`) to simplify the regex (no need for an alternation group or lazy dot matching pattern) and then access `.group(1)`:

```
def extract_id_from_ref(ref):
    m = re.search(r"Cp_6%3A([^&]*)", ref)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Note that neither `_` nor `%` are special regex metacharacters, and do not have to be escaped.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IZ6R9D/2).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *spaces in a regex pattern*, are also taken into account. Furthermore in order to add a backspace to the string, you either have to add `\\` (two backslashes) or use a *raw string*:

So you should write:

```
r"Cp_6\%3A(.*?)(?:\&|$)"
```

If you then match with:

```
def extract_id_from_ref(ref):
    id = re.search(r"Cp_6\%3A(.*?)(?:\&|$)", ref)
    print(id)
```

It should work.